# python while loop not stopping after condition is met?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to eventually create a function that pulls discount codes from a file, sends them to a user, and then deletes them from the file afterword. I'm trying to use a while loop to accomplish this, but it's not stopping when the condition is met. Instead, it's reading to the end of the file every time, and the `len(count)` value is always equal to the number of lines in the file. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
count = []
with open('codes.txt', 'w') as f:
    while len(count) < 10:
        #print(len(count))
        for line in lines:
            if '10OFF' in line:
                count.append(line)
                line = line.replace(line, "USED\n")
                #f.write('USED\n')
                #line = line + ' USED'

                f.write(line)
                print(line)
            #elif '10OFF' not in line:
                #print('not in line')
    else:
        print('all done')
        print(len(count))
```

Comment: Your while condition wont be checked while your are inside the `for` loop.

Comment: My guess is that something is messed up with the `lines` variable. It's perhaps empty in which case the count will never have sufficient items for the loop to terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check should in loop. try this.

```
count = []
with open('codes.txt', 'w') as f:
    #print(len(count))
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '10OFF' in line:
            count.append(line)
            line = line.replace(line, "USED\n")
            #f.write('USED\n')
            #line = line + ' USED'

            f.write(line)
            print(line)
        if len(count) >= 10:
            break

print('all done')
print(len(count))
```

Answer to comment - your lines were deleted after 10.
Open another file for output.

```
with open('codes.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('codes_output.txt', 'w') as fo:
         ...
         fo.write(line)
         ...
```

Comment: Okay, this worked for breaking the loop, but now if i add more than 10 lines in the file, it will delete every line after the first 10. any idea why?

Comment: @jkorn95 you need to open another file to write into.